# Xamarin Forms reading JSON

Tags: json, list, xamarin.forms

So I am retrieving JSON data from my site and this is my code:

The model:

```
    class Reservations
    {
        public string id_reservation { get; set; }
        public string spz { get; set; }
        public string reservation_day { get; set; }
        public string reservation_time { get; set; }
        public string ip_address { get; set; }
    }
```

The connection and parsing:

```
protected async void CheckReservations(string day)
        {
            if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {
                try
                {
    private const string Url = "Urltomysite";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
                    var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
                    List<Reservations> myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reservations>>(content);


                    foreach (Reservations res in myData)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Time:" + res.reservation_time);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("" + e);
                }
            }
        }
```

And the JSON response from my site:

```
[
{
id_reservation: "39",
spz: "NRGH67L",
reservation_day: "2019-01-26",
reservation_time: "14:00",
ip_address: "192.168.137.5"
}
]
```

But when I try to print the reservation_time from List of the Object in the foreach I dont get any results. I am still pretty new to this and got this far from tutorials, so dont know what I am missing.

Thanx for any replies.

Comment: The content is HttpResponse object, right? What is the object you are getting on content while debugging. I suggest to put a breakpoint there and analyse the data in the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a crash prone way of this

```
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      var json = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //using ReadAsStreamAsync() gives you better performance
      List<Reservations> myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reservations>>(json);
      //do the rest jobs
    }
    else
    {
      //alert the api call failed
    }
```